# what is better to place the scripts on the _layout view or in each view

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, asp.net-mvc-3

i am working on an asp.net MVC web application , currently i am managing the scripts as follow:-
1. i have placed the following scripts on the _layout view since they are used by most of the view (but of course not all the views):-

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.14.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

1. then i have added the other scripts to the related views themself if they need them.

**so my question is if this approach will achive better performance since i am not going to load all the scripts on the _layout view?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is best practice.  But just be mindful, if you are using a certain `script` file in a majority of the Views, then I would place that in your _Layout.cshtml as well.  Just because it isn't used in 100% of the Views, doesn't mean it isn't practical and advised to put it in your layout View.

If there are a few or two that uses are particular script, you are right:  Just put it in that View.  But remember by doing this you are repeating yourself, and it could potentionally be a maintenance nightmare if you need to update the script file name or path.

It's a gray area, but I'd be willing to say you are doing the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

Place the scripts that all views are going to use in the _layout.cshtml file.

Then place specific scripts such as the validation ones in the respective views, even better in the Editor templates.

Better yet, use something like Cassette to combine all your scripts into a single .js file, this will make your website faster as the user has to cache a single file and serve a single file. Then you would serve this single .js file from the _layout.cshtml.

Cassette: http://getcassette.net/

SquishIt: http://www.codethinked.com/squishit-the-friendly-aspnet-javascript-and-css-squisher

---

I have a small article on using SquishIt with MVC3, though I prefer Cassette. Both provide similar functionality.

http://sergiotapia.com/2012/01/using-squishit-in-an-asp-net-mvc3-web-application/